# Content not deleting properly

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script to display the output of get-eventlog to csv

```
$File_Name = "$env:tmp\Event_logs.csv"

if(Test-Path $File_Name){
Clear-Content $File_Name
}
$Event_Logs_Content | ConvertTo-Csv | Set-Content $File_Name
start $File_Name
```

But when i executed second time, results for first time still exist in the file and for third time execution first 2 attempts output still exist in file and so on..

i have tried by deleting ~"Files" in tmp path but of no use, please suggest

Comment: Why not just use `Export-Csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get your work done:

```
$File_Name = "$env:tmp\Event_logs.csv"

if(Test-Path $File_Name){
Remove-Item $File_Name -Force
}
$Event_Logs_Content | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File $File_Name -Force
```

Assuming $Event_Logs_Content is having proper values which you want to set it in the file. Because I am not seeing the event logs retrieval code.

Comment: You don't need to delete the file if you use Out-File without -append.

Comment: @bunzab: But i would still prefer that. Its kinda my best practice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, its working now. Used below lines

$File_Name = "$env:tmp\Event_logs.csv"

if(Test-Path $File_Name){
Remove-Item $File_Name -Force
}
$Event_Logs_Content | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File $File_Name -Force